# Python: case insensitive search of text file to return multiple results

Tags: python

Need to read a text file to complete a case insensitive search for substring matches that will then return the appropriate lines where a match exists.

For instance, if a user inputs "aArP" or "AARP" or "AaRp" they will return "aarp" or "Aarp" or "aarpooooooooo" etc.

Below is my code that works for case sensitive matching but I can't quite get regex, etc. to work to bring it all together.

Limited Python experience, just learning, so would appreciate any/all advice!

```
def search_string(string_to_search):
    line_number = 0
    list_of_results = []
    with open("file_name.txt", "r") as read_obj:
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
            if string_to_search in line:
                list_of_results.append((line_number, line.rstrip()))
    return list_of_results

search_term = input("Please provide an input to search: ")

results = search_string(search_term)

print(results)
```

Comment: have you considered `var1_name.lower() == var2_name.lower()` as an option to compare lowercase values on both sides. or `var1_name.lower() in var2_name.lower()`

Comment: One method (without regex) would be to compare the two string in a selected case.  For example: `’MyCAT‘.lower() == ‘mycaT’.lower()`.

Comment: Replace `if string_to_search in line:` by `if string_to_search.lower() in line.lower():` and it will become case insensitive